# Coset Multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

I stumbled upon a statement and I am trying to find an example:

This involves coset multiplication where for H a subgroup of a group G then

$Ha \times Hb=H(ab)$ and $Hc \times Hd=H(cd)$

Then there is the case where $Ha=Hc$ and $Hb=Hd$ but $H(ab)\neq H(cd)$

Is there any example in the integers or any group that satisfy this idea?

Comment: Integers? Not sure what the refers to in this question.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, you have basically answered it yourself:$$H(ab)=(Ha)(Hb)=(Hc)(Hd)=H(cd)\ .$$

Comment: Never mind, I actually got it. thanks guys!

Comment: It should be noted that coset multiplication is only well-defined for subgroups $H$ that are normal in $G$. That is, it's not necessarily the case that $(Ha)(Hb) = H(ab)$; this is only guaranteed when $H \lhd G$.